# How can I disable 4G LTE on stock samsung (SGS3) or CyanogenMod?

Tags: cyanogenmod, mobile-data, 4g

My carrier, Sprint, has a lot of weak 4G coverage.  In areas where I only have one 4G bar, the internet doesn't work.  Every connection times out.  However, these areas often have moderate-to-strong 3G coverage.  In these situations, I would prefer to connect to the 3G network instead of the 4G one.  Is there a way to disable just the 4G connection?  I am looking for a solution in ether the stock Samsung OS shipped with the SGS3 or in CyanogenMod.

Comment: Some carriers allow you to configure this on your account, (i.e. The CLEAR network allows you to go online and set "3G Preferred - Means a connection can be established to either 3G or 4G; If both are available, 3G is used." I was not able to find this for Sprint, but that doesn't mean a call to their customer service rep couldn't help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the code `*#*#4636*#*#` in caller app, you will find a menu called 'Testing', enter in phone information and then in 'set preferred network type' select 'WCDMA only' or 'GSM only'

Comment: I will see if this works.  Is there an alternate way that allows toggling it on and off quickly so that I can use 4G in places where the signal is better?

Comment: Try `*#2263#` and only select non-LTE items.